# moduli of lattices

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-geometry, integer-lattices, moduli-space

Consider the set $M$ of all (rank $g$) lattices in $g$-dimensional complex affine space $C^g$.

Does M identify in some way with Siegel upper half space $H_g$?

Let's say a lattice has CM if it has endomorphism ring bigger than the integers. (This is not the correct definition.)

Is the set of CM lattices dense?

What if we mod out $M$ by some group?